# Plotting over a background python basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

How do you go about plotting data over a background image in Python?

For example if I had some gridded pressure data of shape [180,360] (lat,lon)

I could easily plot data by;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='ortho',resolution='c',lat_0=45,lon_0=0)

lat = np.linspace(-90,90,180)
lon = np.linspace(-180,180,360)

lon,lat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
X, Y = m(lon, lat)

m.contourf(X,Y,Pressure)
plt.show()
```

etc etc. But if I add a background , e.g.

```
m.bluemarble()
```

I cant plot on top of this layer. I've heard of imshow, but how does that take into account gridded data? Not sure how to plot pressure on top of this. Or possibly the alpha attribute in plotting. Thanks!

For example setting alpha to 0.5 in the plt function, I get some horrible mix of colours (and white lines randomly appear);

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that you can't plot over this layer? Do you mean that `m.plot(stuff)` does something unexpected or throws an error?

Comment: It mixes the colors rather than keeping them as seperate layers - I'll post an image as an example

Comment: I don't understand. If you set alpha to be semi-transparent, of cause it will mix the color